# How to get count of matching items in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to get count of matching items in `AutoCompleteTextView`, or checking to see if there is at least one matching item. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would help us help you if we knew what you have tried, and what (undesired) output you are getting? Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The ListAdapter should hold that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own custom view and override  `onFilterComplete`.

```
public class MAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    @Override
    public void onFilterComplete(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "count of matching items: "+ i);
    }

    // Override the constructors
}
```