# How to get the number of items in a dropdown? (AutoCompleteTextView)

Tags: android, kotlin, dropdown, autocompletetextview

Is not in the `resultList` nor the `listAdapter` because those have all the items from the database.

EDIT: `dropdownHeight` always gives -2, no mater how many items it's showing

```
private fun loadProducts(){
    val db = DataBaseHandler(context)
    allProducts = db.readData_AllProducts()!!
    products = db.readData_AllProductsActivePrefix(true, "001")!!
    products.sortBy { it.prod_description }
    resultList.clear()
    for (prod in products)
        resultList.add(prod.prod_description)
    setAdapter()
}

private fun setAdapter(){
    listAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, resultList)
    etSearch.setAdapter(listAdapter)
}
```

I've also searched in my `AutocompleteTextView` (named `etSearch` in this case) all the options containing the word "dropdown" and had no luck.

Someone posted a similar question like 4 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485479/how-to-get-count-of-matching-items-in-autocompletetextview) but there's no answers.

I want to check the size so if there's only 1 left, grab it from the `textChangeListener`

Bonus question! I would like to know if there's a more efficient way to pass all the prod.prod_description to the `resultList` at once (not using the `for` statement, my API target is 19*)

Thanks in advance!

*I'm developing a low-resources Point of Sales app so it can run in old devices

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this

HTML

```
<select data-attr="dropdown" id="input1">
   <option value="Male" id="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female" id="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Now if you want to do it with jquery use this

```
len = $('#input1 option').length;
```

Or if you want to use vanilla javascript

```
len = document.getElementById("input1").length;
```

In both cases "len" will be 2

I know this select/dropdown is not yours, but you will get the idea.

Comment: The problem here is I have like 3k items, and is growing all the time... how do I add every option programmatically? Also I don't use HTML in android with Kotlin... thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid i can't help you then. If you want i'll remove my answer